# What does the three colored dots in Gestures mean/indicate?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Th three colored-dots at the bottom of the screen?

What do they mean, represent? Or just for show?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're just there for the show, or potentially a harmless bug. The mystery dots appeared in Windows Phone 8.1 when the **touch** settings were upgraded to **[gestures and touch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/gestures-touch/9nblggh319dm)**. In phone coming pre-installed with Windows 10 Mobile, they appear after upgrading the gestures and touch settings app to version number 2.3.0.7